# Cordova use / in apps for root directory

Tags: java, android, cordova, cordova-3

I'm building an Android app with cordova 3.5.0 and have some images on my page like so

```
<img src="/images/img.jpg"/>
```

The issue is that this wont work with Android and I get image placeholders instead. I would have to give an absolute path or a relative path in the form `../images/img.jpg` for the image to display.

Is there a way I can just use `/`, it would make things much simpler since my app uses a router and paths can nest further down. It would be difficult to keep adjusting the relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

On my personal experience with Android and Java Strings you should use it double like this

```
<img src="//images//img.jpg" />
```

Hope to help you...